# How to duplicate rows in excel based on column content?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have following data in excel table

```
r1 r2 r3 r4 r5
v1 v2 r3 r4 r5
x1 x2    r4 r5
```

is it posible (and how) to convert this data to structure like:

```
r1 r2 r3
r1 r2 r4
r1 r2 r5
v1 v2 r3
v1 v2 r4
v1 v2 r5
x1 x2 r4
x1 x2 r5
```

thanks in advance

Comment: So your excel will have 5 columns always and you want to duplicate rows based upon last 3 columns?

Comment: I believe this is not duplicate... what you want is ***create three row of one row*** based on the last three column data. For this you will need to write ***MACRO***

Comment: @NirajNawanit exactly. Fahim Pakar, i guess i need to write macro for this, but i don't know much about VBA. Do You have any guidelinses where i can start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim wsIlRow As Long, wsOlRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    Set wsI = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsO = Sheets("Sheet2")

    wsIlRow = wsI.Range("A" & wsI.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    wsOlRow = 1

    For i = 1 To wsIlRow
        For j = 3 To 5
            If Len(Trim(wsI.Cells(i, j).Value)) <> 0 Then
                wsO.Range("A" & wsOlRow).Value = wsI.Range("A" & i).Value
                wsO.Range("B" & wsOlRow).Value = wsI.Range("B" & i).Value
                wsO.Range("C" & wsOlRow).Value = wsI.Cells(i, j).Value
                wsOlRow = wsOlRow + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This method uses arrays to avoid range loops. It dumps a range from column A:E to F:H

[image]

```
Sub MoveEM()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim X
    Dim Y
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim lngCnt As Long
    Set rng1 = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
    X = rng1.Value2

    ReDim Y(1 To 3 * UBound(X, 1), 1 To 3)
    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
        For lngCol = 1 To 3
            lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
            Y(lngCnt, 1) = X(lngRow, 1)
            Y(lngCnt, 2) = X(lngRow, 2)
            Y(lngCnt, 3) = X(lngRow, 2 + lngCol)
        Next
    Next
   [f1].Resize(UBound(Y, 1), UBound(Y, 2)) = Y

   End Sub
```